# Get data from intent extras after activity has been

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 activities. They are launching one another.

Activity A > B > C.

Each of them is passing data using intent.put extra to the next activity.

Problem is - when I navigate from activity B to activity C and click back - I go to activity B but can't restore data which came originally from intent from activity A.

```
// activity A starting activity B
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChaptersActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(CHAPTER_NAME, R.string.chapter_1_title);
startActivity(intent);

// Activity B saving data from intent extra in bundle and starting activity 
 public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
      outState.putInt(MainActivity.CHAPTER_NAME, getIntent().getExtras().getInt(MainActivity.CHAPTER_NAME));       
    }

Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChapterDetails.class);
startActivity(intent);

// after going back from activity C to activity B by pressing back button - method onCreate is called, but Bundle onSaveInstanceState is null. As well as getIntent() is null.
```

As a workaround, I'm thinking about startActivityForResult when going from activity B to C. Or using persistent storage. But not sure this is the correct way to do things. Any tips?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: post your code here

Comment: You could store data in SharedPreferences, or in a database (SQLite) and have you data across the whole application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for a solution for some time I came up with this:

First of all, there are "back" and "up". I meant "Up" in my question. Up navigation is not the same thing as the bottom-left or physical back button. It recreates the up Activity by default, unless I set the launch mode to "singleTop" for the up Activity in the manifest.

Or I need to write the code in my activity C to make "Up" button act like "Back"

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```